# jQuery.waypoint - direction is undefined

Tags: jquery, jquery-waypoints

I have a problem using the waypoint plugin as many tutorials like http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-tutorials/create-a-sticky-navigation-header-using-jquery-waypoints/ suggest.

Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

jQuery(function() {
var nav_container = jQuery("#menu-wrapper");
var nav = jQuery("#menu");
nav_container.waypoint(function(event, direction) {

    jQuery("#fixed").toggleClass('stickyfixed');
    jQuery('#zweitenavigation').toggleClass('invisible');
    alert(direction);
    var new_height  = (direction === "down") ? '92px' : '195px';
    jQuery("#header").animate({'height': new_height}, 300);
},{offset:50}
);
});
</script>
```

The problem is that

```
direction === "down"
```

does not evaluate to true or false, it is simply undefined. Therefore the animation is just fired once.

Does anyone has an idea where the problem could be located?
The toggleClass works fine btw.

Thanks for help and best regards
stephan

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Waypoints version 2.0 got rid of the `event` parameter. There is now only `direction`. The tutorial you are referencing has made a pretty big error in linking to this new version of Waypoints without updating their tutorial to match the new handler signature.

Comment: THANKS for this answer. It did the trick. I was already wondering if I'm the only one arround with this problem!

Comment: A good way to help others with this same problem that happen upon this page is to mark the answer above as "Accepted".

Comment: Oh, sorry that I missed that! Best regards